# Sentence structure and form

Tags: grammar, sentence, descriptive-grammar, objects, word-formation

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> "The great sea creature came alongside Lotty and nudged him, so he climbed on board its strong back.

I don't get what sentence structure the second part is.

"he climbed back on board" sounds correct to me, but why is "its strong back" added right after?

Can it have a place there? and, if yes, I'll be grateful if you could state some examples such as the above-mentioned.

Comment: The sentence says that Lotty climbed onto the creature's back, not that he climbed _back_ on (had he been on it before?).

Comment: The creature had been there before, yes. You can actually remove "back". it's been mentioned in my book that way, too.

Comment: The **back** (noun) is the creature's back. I don't think you *can* remove **back**. If you do, you have to remove "on board" too, since you don't "climb on board" an animal: you climb on board a ship. But if you refer to the back of the creature, as if it were a boat's deck, then it makes sense.

Comment: I didn't ask whether the creature had been there before, but whether Lotty had ridden it before. If he hasn't. he can't climb _back_ on.

Comment: I meant Lotty, sorry. I guess I have to put my question better. I didn't mean if "back" should've been there or not. I mean whether the sentence structure is valid. Leave the first part. The second part says "he climbed back on board its strong back", is the sentence trying to describe "board", which is its strong back? if yes, shouldn't it be like "he climbed back on board, its strong back" or use an underscore? the text is "board its back", which sounds weird to me

Comment: Please see [**on board**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/on_board). *He climbed / on board / its strong back.* The sentence is perfectly good. Please note: if you want a reader to notice your comments, add their user name like @WeatherVane.

Comment: Thanks! the examples given helped a ton. One last question: Can we say like "on board (of) its strong back" instead?

Comment: No: the sentence is correct: on board the ship / the creature / the train.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for helping!